# Has the US military ever admitted a strategic mistake for an entire war?

Tags: united-states, military, afghanistan

Lloyd Austin, the US Defense Secretary in a hearing before Congress said:

> The fact that the Afghan army, that we and our partners trained, simply melted away, in many cases without firing a shot, took is all by surprise. And it would be dishonest to claim otherwise.

In other words, he admitted a strategic error in their exit strategy from Afganistan. In fact, the military recommended a small force of 2,500 US troops be kept in the country but were over-ruled by Biden's administration who replied that this would only escalate the war.

**Pointedly, he did not say whether the entire War on Terror in Afghanistan was a strategic error. Has a defense secretary ever admitted a strategic error for an entire war? For example, that of Vietnam. Or are these assessments only made by historians and political scientists?**

Comment: Would you only be interested in contemporaneous statements? Or if a defense secretary said that the Vietnam War (for instance) was an error after they had left office, would that be acceptable? Or if a defense secretary who had not started a war called it an error, would that qualify?

Comment: I am thinking of someone like Colin Powell in the first case, who said years later that had they been in possession of the full intelligence, the invasion of Iraq would have been a mistake.

Comment: @Obie 2.0: All of them, the poster can take his or her pick. But I'm predominantly interested in the case where the secretary is still in office. I'm already aware that Robert McNamara, who was defense secretary between 1961-68, according to a NYT review of his 1995 interview realised early on that 'the war was futile' but only admitted that late in life. In fact, in his memour he said 'it was wrong, terribly wrong'. He moved from understanding the war was futile, and so a strategic error,  to understand that there was no moral case for the war either. Too bad, he wasn't able to speak ...

Comment: @Obie 2.0: ... that hard truth to power, that is in Congress. It may be the case that other defense secretaries were able to do so. The Vietnam war ended in 1975.

Comment: @Obie 2.0: As far as I know, Colin Powell was Secretary of State rathervthan Secretary of Defense. Of course he was also a four star general.

Comment: Headline says “US military”, question says “defense secretary”. Those are two very different things.

Comment: @Relaxed: No, I've expanded in the body of the question what I mean.

Comment: You haven't “expanded” as much as “contradicted”.

Comment: @Relaxed: Untrue.

Comment: @Relaxed: You're simply ignoring what I'm saying and taking advantage of the pedantry of words to suppose I'm contradicting myself by deliberately choosing opposing meanings. I'm not. Are you responsible for the closure of this question - as you seem to be the only one complaining about it?

Comment: I didn't vote to close the question (I never do when I answer) and the list of people who did is actually public. I engaged honestly with you and you are just picking fights, don't be surprised if people prefer to close the question. I still think the distinction between military and secretary of defense is important, far from mere pedantry. If you want to discuss any of this further, you should make an effort to understand that point.

Comment: @Relaxed: I am not picking fights. I didn't approach you with concerns about my question. You are the one that approachrd me with your so-called distinction between the military in my headline question and the political in the body of my question. Again, you are spinning in the direction of confusion. You also stayed that the Secretary of Defense simply couldn't anything other than follow orders from the President. But of course he can, the Nuremberg Trials established that following orders in the chain of commandvis no excuse for war crimes. And the Bertrand Russell Trials established ...

Comment: @Relaxed: ... that war crimes was committed in Vietnam. Moreover, there is the crime of aggression which the USA is blatantly guilty of.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You seem to be very keen on debating general moral principles instead of accepting an answer to the question you asked. I didn't express any opinion on that, one way or the other. Are you at all interested in the way the military and government works or not?

Comment: Incidentally, you have absolutely no idea how I feel about the wars in Vietnam or Afghanistan, whether they were justified or effective, etc. It's not because the US government works that way that it is necessarily right or an excuse for anything, those are two very different things. Do you think the US government is a model of respect for international law?

Answer (score 5):

### Probably not, but some came close

My understanding of the question is that it primarily is asking whether a Secretary of Defense who held that office during a war ever admitted that the war itself as a strategic error.
That seems unlikely, and some searching was unable to find an example, although that does not prove definitively that it never happened. In the USA, there is a strong pro-military sentiment, and so there is little to motivate a Secretary of Defense to say that a war was wholly a mistake, unless they truly believed it themselves. As of now, only two or three wars of the dozens that the United States has fought are both well-known and generally perceived as complete failures: the wars in Afghanistan, Vietnam, and perhaps Iraq.

That said, one can find a few examples of people who came close.

I believe that the closest would be **Robert McNamara**, who served as Secretary of Defense during the Vietnam War, [wrote the following](https://time.com/6052980/vietnam-robert-mcnamara-memoir/) in his memoirs:

> We in the Kennedy and Johnson administrations who participated in the decisions on Vietnam acted according to what we thought were the principles and traditions of this nation. We made our decisions in light of those values. Yet we were wrong, terribly wrong. We owe it to future generations to explain why.

In the surrounding context, he does not *quite* say that the war itself was a mistake, and he mainly criticizes (most) of his own decisions around it, but it is easy to read between the lines and think that he is talking about the war in general.

Another person who somewhat approached this type of statement is **Colin Powell**, Secretary of State (though not Defense) during the war in Iraq, who [defended the decision to invade](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.nbcnews.com/news/amp/ncna422566) while implying that it would have been a strategic error *if* they had known the true intelligence:

> “If we had known the intelligence was wrong, we would not have gone into Iraq. But the intelligence community, all 16 agencies, assured us that it was right,” he said on NBC’s “Meet the Press.”

Of course, one might not wish to read too much into this, because he also said this about the invasion of Baghdad:

> So I think it was a great success. But the biggest thing was the American people just absolutely fell in love with their armed forces once again.

An additional mention should probably go to **James Mattis**, who [called the Iraq War a strategic mistake in exactly those words](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.businessinsider.com/mattis-iraq-war-mistake-2016-12%3famp), but was not Secretary of Defense until two administrations afterward, and did not make the statements while Secretary of Defense nor near the beginning of the war.

> We will probably look back on the invasion of Iraq as a mistake, a strategic mistake

Comment: -1: @Obie 2.0: I've already pointed out this situation in the comments above in reply to your questions. Moreover, Robert McNamara 'truly believed' the war was a mistake early on in his career as Defense Secretary - so according tobyour answer, he should have admitted so in Congress. That would be accountability in action.  The interesting question here, then, is why did he not admit this in public, that is Congress, and what pressures were put on him.

Comment: @Mozibur - The answer is likely "no, but these two people probably came closest," which is what I wrote above. Sorry if that does not satisfy you? As for McNamara, he is the closest to what you were asking, so it is relevant to mention him, and I was not reading your comments while writing the answer.

Comment: Seeing the reluctance of people to admit their own (or other people's) military mistakes after the fact, as evidenced in these two quotes, one might easily see how unlikely it is that the architects of a war (the Secretaries of Defense) would admit them publicly, while in office, and probably while the war was ongoing. Not to mention that a fair amount of searching did not turn up any such statements.

Comment: Not at all. I'm simply pointing out that you appear to be riffing off my comment above. I don't consider that good ethics. Do you, or no?

Comment: @Mozibur - It doesn't really matter whether I do or not, because your assumption is not correct. I wrote the answer with the two examples of McNamara and Powell before I read your comments. You can tell from the bit in the beginning where it says "my understanding of the question is" and not "as noted in the comments, the question is."

Comment: I *did* make the edit saying that Colin Powell was Secretary of State after reading your comments, though. If you like, I can attribute that in the answer.

Comment: It isn't that uncommon for a public official to remain in a posting implementing a policy they disagree with.  Motives are various, but one of them can be a belief that someone else would struggle even more to "do the right thing".  That's certainly the charitable view for Hinshaw remaining as Chief Health officer in Alberta for covid, for example, despite an abject policy failure from the PM.  However, if such an official remains in their position you would also **not** expect public criticism of the administration's policy, else they could not fulfill their role.  +1 to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Strategic decisions of that importance are inherently political and, in the US, the president's responsibility. The military's job is to offer several solutions to reach the goals it is given and assess the risks and costs (human and material) of the various options. Military leaders (especially retired staff-level experts, rarely active-duty top-level commanders themselves) often complain of changing or imprecise goals, which can also be a way to blame civilians for things that go wrong, but have to tread carefully when questioning a president's decision to start or end a war.

Comment: -1: The Secretary of Defensecis a political position. It's not only the President's position that is political.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Indeed but he or she is still in a subordinate position. But, as I commented, you asked about the military. You created that confusion. Not that this detracts or contradicts my answer, hard to see how this justifies a downvote either way.

Comment: The term is first amongst equals. The relations of power amongst the elite is not a simple hierarchy. I asked about the military in the headline question and the Secretary of Defense represents the military. There is no confusion here.

Comment: What are you supposing that I mean about whether the US military has ever admitted a strategic mistake for a war? That I ask every soldier, sailor and airman? That's just nonsensical. It's implicit acknowledged in such a question that its a representative of the military. A general say, or a political appointment representing the latter. And it's the latter choice I was interested in as I explained in my question.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You should try to understand what I wrote instead of trying to score points, you might learn a thing or two. The US miliary has spokespeople and does communicate as an institution. Otherwise you might be interested in the joint chiefs of staff or their chairman. That's who represents the military, *not* the secretary of defense.

Comment: Also, there are countries where that's how it works but the US cabinet members are definitely not equal to the president. “First among equals” is indeed a specific term and it simply doesn't apply here. You seem to labor under severe misconceptions regarding the structure of the US government and military chain of command.

Comment: You seem to be painting yourself into a corner here: Does the secretary of defense “represent” the military or is it a political position? You draw the line where you want but my point regarding the distinction holds in any case. The military doesn't decide to go to war on its own and is not supposed to openly question that decision. I didn't suppose you cared about the opinion of the rank and file but I did expect you to be able to understand this pretty basic notion and thought it would be a useful answer if you are genuinely interested in the question, not a reason to argue endlessly.

Comment: It's both, of course. Like the positionnof the Joint Chiefs of Staff. It's you that are playing around with pedantry. Whilst the Secretary of Defense doesn't decide go to war, he can state that it's his strong belief that a certain war is a strategic blunder and resign. It's unconscionable to me how, say for Robert McNamara, who was Secretary of Defense 1961-68 thought the Vietnam war was futile and didn't resign. Why prosecute a war when you know there is no defense for it?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Resigning is indeed an option, open criticism not so much. That observation does not excuse the whole confusion between military and civilian leadership or the blatant nonsense about the US president being a “first among equal”. I am not American, I don't have an opinion or interest in passing judgment on Robert McNamara and I don't see the connection between this and my answer.

Comment: No, there is confusion here. You're simply spinning this question in the direction of confusion. Resigning is an option and McNamara might have taken that option, or any other Secretary of Defense.  The Joint Chiefs of Staff might have taken that option. Or a four star general. You're making a fuss where no fuss is required. As you are the only person complaining about my question, are you the one responsible for closing my question? It is fine as is.

Comment: @MoziburUllah If your question is whether a US Secretary of Defense ever resigned, you can look that up relatively easily. Meanwhile, it's a fact that there is an important distinction between political civilian positions and the military itself or that the military is not expected to decide on strategic objectives, much less publicly comment on them. You seem to absolutely refuse that notion for moral reasons but that's irrelevant. That's still the way it works.

Comment: I already answered your baseless accusation about closing your question. I am the only person to offer you practical advice instead of just shunning you and you can easily verify that I had nothing to do with the closure. You're accusing me of “making a fuss” but you're getting worked up all on your own.